# Go chum chum chum

Tags: grammar

1. It went chum chum. (the chewing movement)
2. It is going chum chum.
3. It goes chum chum. (I don't know what it means but)

Are these all correct?

Comment: I've never heard the term "chum chum" (AmE).

Comment: If I understand what you mean, I think the term we use idiomatically is "[nom](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nom+nom+nom)".

Comment: Where did you read/hear this? Possibly do you mean *yum yum*?

Comment: WHAT went chum chum chum?  Is "it" here used as in "it is raining"?  Or is there actually some person or thing ("it") that is making that sound?

Comment: Are you just asking about conjugating the verb "to go"?  (in which case the "chum chum chum" is irrelevant), or asking whether it's OK to use the verb "to go" in reference to making a sound? (Yes, if is; pigs go "oink"—but then the conjugation is irrelevant!)

Comment: Or do you imagine that you told us something about the TIME frame, that would allow us to help you choose an appropriate verb tense? You did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we accept *chum chum chum* to mean the chewing movement then yes, all three versions of the sentence are correct.

(**Note:** *Chum chum chum* is not idiomatic for North American English, nor for British English if I'm not mistaken.  We don't really have a proper word for it beyond *nom*, as suggested in the comments by Catija, and that is fairly recent slang.)

The first sentence is describing the behavior of something in the past, perhaps a dog that was eating peanut butter.

The second sentence is describing action that is ongoing.  I gave my dog some peanut butter and it is currently chewing and licking it away.

The third sentence is descriptive of the general behavior of dogs when given peanut butter.

> Q: What does your dog do if you give it peanut butter?
>   A: It goes chum chum.

Comment: How can you say the examples are correct if you don't know what "chum chum" means? Without that information, this is just a question about tenses of *to go*.

Comment: @user3169- I believe that is exactly what the question is about-  That is the variable in the three examples and the meaning of *chum chum* is provided in the question.  More particularly I suspect the question is about the idiomatic form of *to go* when used to describe noises as metonym for an action.

Comment: @user3169 It really doesn't matter what the meaning of *chum chum* is, as long as we have a vague understanding of the type of word it was meant to be.  The sentences would still be correct if they all read "kabloozle" in place of "chum chum," it *was* a question about verb tenses and meanings.

Comment: OK, but then that should be in the question title.